# Derivative of a piecewise defined function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I want to ask something about the definition of derivative. If we have a function like this $ f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    x^2+1       & \quad \text{if } x<0 \\
    \cos x  & \quad \text{if } x\ge 0\\
  \end{cases}
  $ 
 and we want to compute the derivetive in $x_0=0$ why is necessary to compute this with the definition of derivative? It will be wrong to find the the derivative of $ x^2+1$ and of $\cos x$ with types and to compute in $x_0=0$? Could you give me an example which is compute only with the limit and it is not compute with formulas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your function is not continuous in $0$

Comment: You are right stity. i fix it

Answer (score 0):

For your example formulas work (with some caution).  Define $g(x)=\cos x$ and $h(x)=x^2 + 1$.  Then $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\geq 0$ and $f(x)=h(x)$ for all $x\leq 0$.  There is no trouble finding the derivative for $x\not=0$,
but what to do at $x=0$?

Well the (right-hand) derivative of $g(x)$ at this point is $g'(0)=g_+'(0)=0$ and so the right-hand derivative of $f$ must be the same, i.e., $f_+'(0)=0$.

And the (left-hand) derivative of $h(x)$ at this point is $h'(0)=h_-'(0)=0$ and so the left-hand derivative of $f$ must be the same, i.e., $f_-'(0)=0$.

Since both sides agree then $f'(0)$ must be this common value.

We didn't need to use the definition of the derivative--we used *properties* of the derivative and computed merrily the way any calculus student would want to.

Doesn't always work.  Try $$ F(x) = x^{ 2} \sin x^{-2}$$ with $F(0)=0$.  None of your calculus skills help.  Sure you can compute $F'(x)$ for any $x\not=0$ by your formulas, but that doesn't lead to an answer for $F'(0)$.  You simply return to the definition of the derivative and compute that limit as best you can.  (Or examine the graph closely for ideas.)